# Complexity of dependant loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, complexity-theory

2I have developed an algorithm and I'm trying to document its time complexity in the most detailed way and I'm stuck with a problem.

The algorithm looks like that :

```
for i=0:n {
    task 1;
    task 2;
    for j=0:i {
        task 3;
    }
    task 4;
}
```

So I documented my complexity by saying that the task 1 has a complexity of O(t1), ... 
But when I try to explain the task 3 I'm stuck because it will essentially be executed i times and I planned to say that the complexity of the lagorithm is n times the complexity of task 1 + task 2 + i * task 3 + task 4. And as i will depend on n I don't really see what would the best way to present the things.

I understand that if the tasks 1, 2 and 4 didn't existed the complexity will be O(n^2). But I don't know how to present that with coherence with my previous explaination.

I hope that makes sense, thank you for your help.

Comment: Task 3 will be executed 1+2+3+.. +n = n*(n+1)/2 times. So the time complexity for task 3 only is O(n^2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to count them separately.

Task 3 is executed: `1+2+3+...+n` = [`n(n+1)/2`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2%2B3%2B...%2Bn) times.

Tasks 1, 2 and 4 are executed `n` times each.

So (assuming each task takes `O(1)`) we have a complexity of

```
O(n(n+1)/2 + 3n) = O(n²/2 + n/2 + 3n) = O(n²)
```

(constant factors and asymptotically smaller terms can be ignored in big-O notation).

---

More generally (if each task doesn't necessarily take `O(1)`) we can say the complexity is:

```
O(t3*n² + n*(t1 + t2 + t4))
```

Where `ti` represents how long task `i` takes.